# I want to make gui with python to display table in RDS MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, database, user-interface, rds

I want to make gui with python to display table in RDS MySQL DB but I have 
that error

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
 File "GUI.py", line 30, in query
 records = c.fetchall()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 488, in fetchall
  raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
  InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

the code

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import sqlite3
import mysql.connector


root = Tk()
root.title('welcome reham')
#root.iconbitmap('@/home/A/x/GUI.xbm')
root.geometry("400x400")

#create query botton to show records in DB
def query():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="*****",
                                 user="admin",
                                 passwd="******",
                                 database="attendance1")
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute = ("SELECT *, oid FROM empolyee")
    records = c.fetchall()
    print(records)

    print_records = ''
    for record in records:
    print_records += str(records) + "/n"
    query_labal = labal(root, text=print_records)
    query_labal.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=137)
connection.commit()
connection.close()

#create query buttom
query_btn = Button(root, text="show records", command=query)
query_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=137)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it has to be `c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM empolyee")` without `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute query it has to be

```
c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM empolyee")
```

without `=`

---

Using `=` you created variable `c.execute` instead of executing query so later `fetchall()` couldn't get results - because query was not executed - and it shows `No result set to fetch from.`

Comment: now i do that c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM empolyee")  but i have another error ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'oid' in 'field list'

Comment: It can means you don't have column `old` in table `empolyee`. You could test it directly in database using any database viewer/editor - ie [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). Maybe it wil show more details about problem. Or you will see if table has field `old`.

Comment: thank you are right , i have another error  
 File "GUI.py", line 40, in query
    query_labal = labal(root, text=print_records)
NameError: global name 'labal' is not defined

Comment: read error again and answer for question "where I defined `labal`?" You will see that you didn't define it. It seems you need `Label` instead of `labal`.